# Play audio repeatly with bufferWaveProvider

Tags: naudio

I'm trying to output four different audio signal to four channels separately with MultiplexingWaveProvider. I used BufferWaveProvider for each audio signal. However, I also want to play the signal repeatly without stop in between. But I cannot set the position for BufferWaveProvider. How should I solve this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedWaveProvider` is not the best choice for this scenario. You would normally make some kind of looping `WaveStream` (or `IWaveProvider`) whose Read method repeatedly returns data from a file or memory buffer.

See this article here: http://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you so much for the answer! If I use WaveStream and mix four audio file to a mixer, will these four audio output to the four different channels separately on my device, or they will be mixed to one single output so that each of the four channels will output the same mixed audio? I need the four channels to output four different singnals repeatedly.

Comment: in this case I'd recommend passing Looping providers into a Muliplexing provider